# Convert string of date to datetime object in format YYYY-MM_DD

Tags: python, datetime

How would you convert a string of 1/6/23 (6 January 2023 or 2023-01-06) to the date time format 2023-01-06 in Python?

```py
chosen_start_date = "1/6/23"

print(type(chosen_start_date)
print(type(strptime(chosen_start_date,"%#m/%#d/%Y").date()))
```

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior - e.g. `%#m` is not a valid format code.

Comment: You can try something like that ``output_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, input_format)..strftime(output_format)``, input_date is your string chosen_start_date , tell me if you want me to help you with that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might be interested in `dateutil` which parses all sorts of date representations:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
    
    chosen_start_date = "1/6/23"
    
    my_date = parse(chosen_start_date, dayfirst = False)
    
    print(my_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

As I said in my comment, you can use the datetime module in Python to convert the date format from 1/6/23 to 2023-01-06. Here's an example with the full code:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '1/6/23'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%y')
new_date_str = datetime.strftime(date_obj, '%Y-%m-%d')

print(new_date_str)
```

The print outputs 2023-01-06, hope it helps